# Could not find out the solution for following error

Tags: xcode, cordova, extjs

We trying to build sencha on "ios" platform. But after performing command-  sencha app build -run native, it gives following error.

Command Used: **sencha app build -run native**

> The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   **/Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human Rights/UNHR/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:436:** The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   **/Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human Rights/UNHR/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17:** The following error occurred while executing this line:  
>  
>   **/Users/test/Desktop/UNHR_New 2/UNHR2/UNHR/UN Human Rights/UNHR/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:66:** The following error occurred while executing this line:  
>  
>   **jar:file:/Users/test/bin/Sencha/Cmd/6.2.1.29/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant>/antlib.xml:674:** shellscript returned: 1

Comment: Any reason you are using options -run native. If you remove them is build working ?

Comment: Using Command : sencha app build native
It is still terminating build process in between

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the root account to execute the command.

Comment: Have tried with root account too, but still no changes are displaying on terminal.